# Three.js shading of model looks strange

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

After quiete a time at google iam still clueless
why shading on this models look so strange.

I try to import a *.3DX3 Model with Three.js.
I dont got normals in this files, that why iam using

```
mergedTriangles.computeFaceNormals();
mergedTriangles.computeVertexNormals();
```

to calculate this stuff.

Example 1: [image: Example1]

With activated:

```
scene.add( new THREE.FaceNormalsHelper( connectedMesh ) );
scene.add( new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( connectedMesh ) );
scene.add( new THREE.WireframeHelper( connectedMesh ) );
```

Example 2: [image: Example 2]

More complicated Model without the helpers, because u wont se anything when they are activated.

Does somebody have an idea wht could be wrong by just looking at the picture?
The whole code is quiete long, so plz ask for special thing you could need for
analysis ;)

Comment: Can you provide a live example?